# Blog link is relative, while it should be absolute

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The blog link in the site switcher for Meta leads to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/blog.stackexchange.com` while it should lead to `http://blog.stackexchange.com`

This is due to the link having `href="blog.stackexchange.com"`, which is missing the protocol.